# Field is undefined when fails to meet ng-maxlength requirement

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I'm new to AngularJs/Web stuff, seems it should be basic stuff but I struggle to find solution to this problem...

I have a ModalWindow in which user can enter a comment. In case if this comments exceeds X number of characters Saving should be prevented (+some error message). So I thought `ng-maxlength` directive should do the trick, but it behaves strangely.

When length requirement is passed, then $scope.fieldName contains data (which is as expected), but in case if user enters more than allowed characters - then $scope.fieldName is `undefined` and trying to access field's $error field throws an exception.

From what I've seen in this case field's `$error.maxlength` should have been set instead...

So any ideas, suggestions on how to fix this?

//in View

```
    <div class="display-field notator-holder">
        <textarea class="notator"
                  cols="20"
                  id="something"
                  name="fieldName"
                  ng-model="fieldName"
                  ng-maxlength="14"
                  rows="5" hidden>
        </textarea>
    </div>
```

//...in Controller

```
$scope.saveChanges = function () {
    if ($scope.fieldName.$error.maxlength) 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is behaving as expected. What you are missing is, you need to access the form items from form. Model value defaults to nothing when there is nothing ie. when there's an error in validation.

Here's an example.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="meForm">
    <textarea class="notator" cols="20" id="something" name="textArea" ng-model="fieldName" ng-maxlength="14" rows="5">
    </textarea>
    <p ng-show="meForm.textArea.$error.maxlength">Oi! Too long matey!</p>
    <p>Value = {{fieldName ? fieldName : "Invalid/Nothing"}}</p>
    <p>{{meForm.textArea}}</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! This is working, But just a quick question - this html is used to display input data in a `modalwindow`, is it `ok` to use form tag in such case?

Comment: I can't think of a reason not. If your modal is self contained then wrap the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try using only **maxlength** instead of **ng-maxlength** which will restrict user to enter more than the given limit to it as shown in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wZpIK2kK9809i6yxnlwa?p=preview).

**Template:**

```
<textarea class="notator" cols="20" id="something" name="textArea" 
      ng-model="fieldName" maxlength="14" rows="5"></textarea>
<p ng-show="meForm.textArea.$error.maxlength">Oi! Too long matey!</p>
<p>Value = {{fieldName ? fieldName : "Invalid/Nothing"}}</p>
<p>{{meForm.textArea}}</p>
```